# Processing - The constructor ArrayList<Class>(Class) does not exist

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

do i fundamentally not understand arraylist? why can't i make an arraylist of class instances?

i'm literally just trying to make an array list of my class 'Vert' called 'v1'- here's the relevant code

```
    class Vert{
      float x;
      float y;
      Vert(float x, float y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
      }
      float getX(){
        return x;
      }
      float getY(){
        return y;
      }
    }

    ArrayList<Vert> v1 = new ArrayList<Vert>(new Vert(-10,10),new Vert(10,-10));
```

and i'm getting the error

```
    The constructor "ArrayList<shape_rendering.Vert>(Vert, Vert)" does not exist
```

seems like that's exactly the only constructor that could exist? what am i doing wrong here

::EDIT::
so here's the '.add' method in the context of the class

```
    class Vert{
      float x;
      float y;
      Vert(float x, float y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
      }
      float getX(){
        return x;
      }
      float getY(){
        return y;
      }
    }
    class Shape{
      ArrayList<Vert> verts;
      float h;
     Shape(ArrayList<Vert> verts,float h){
       this.verts = verts;
       this.h = h;
     }
     ArrayList<Vert> getVerts(){
       return verts; 
     }

    }



    ArrayList<Vert> v1 = new ArrayList<Vert>();
    v1.add(new Vert(-10,0));
    v1.add(new Vert(0,-10));
    v1.add(new Vert(10,0));
    v1.add(new Vert(0,10));



    Shape s1 = new Shape(new ArrayList<Vert>(v1),10);

    void drawShape(Shape s1){
      ArrayList<Vert> v = s1.getVerts();
      beginShape();
      for(int i = 0;i < v.size();i ++){
        vertex(v.get(i).getX(),v.get(i).getY());
      }
      endShape(CLOSE);
    }

    void setup(){
      size(400,400);
    }

    void draw(){
      background(255);
      drawShape(s1);
    }
```

and i'm getting a syntax error on all the add lines -

```
    Syntax error on(s), misplaced construct(s)
```

Comment: also i've tried just using v2.add() but that doesn't work either

Comment: Where exactly are you defining the array, In the same class or other classes like `Main` ?

Comment: for the sake of troubleshooting i tried this exact block of text in a blank processing project

Comment: The constructor of [`ArrayList`](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) accepts just 1 integral argument, the initial capacity.  You have to add each item separately and dynamically: `v1.add(new Vert(-10,10));` `v1.add(new Vert(10,-10));`

Comment: i tried that, no luck. i can try again with the specific code

Comment: okay so that works in my isolated troubleshooting file, but not in the context of the (only slightly bigger) class. but it seems to be giving me a syntax error now?

Comment: ArrayList<Vert> v1 = new ArrayList<Vert>(new Vert(-10,10),new Vert(10,-10)); should be changed to ArrayList<Vert> v1 = new ArrayList<>(); v1.add(new Vert(-10, 10)); v1.add(new Vert(10, -10);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do any of the following:

1. `List<Vert> v1 = new ArrayList<Vert>(Arrays.asList(new Vert(-10,10),new Vert(10,-10)));`
2. `List<Vert> v1 = List.of(new Vert(-10,10),new Vert(10,-10));`

Comment: it doesn't recognize 'List'

Comment: import `java.util.List`

Comment: well now it doesn't recognize 'of'

Comment: what are Lists for? seems like that's what arrays are for. why am i unable to do this with arraylists

Comment: You need to add `import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;` at the top.

Comment: seems like .add works if i just put it in the setup class actually, thanks